# MyBatis: Autoscan for type aliases

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a MyBatis mapper.xml file with this entry :

```
<select id="findAll"
            resultType="User">
...
</select>
```

... the "User" class is in this package :

```
com.company.model.User
```

... and in application.properties I have this entry :

```
mybatis.type-aliases-package = com.company.model
```

And everything works fine.

After refactoring and moving some classes into sub-packages MyBatis can't find them anymore during autoscan.

Package structure is now like this :

```
com.company.entity.users.User
com.company.entity.departments.Department
com.company.entity.students.Student
```

I've tried (among many other variations: with '/' instead of '.', without 'classpath:', etc) :

```
mybatis.type-aliases-package = classpath:com.company.entity.*
```

but couldn't make it work.

How can I tell MyBatis to scan under all sub-packages of package "com.company.entity"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According [Mybatis configuration](http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/#Configuration) you can use delimiters to separate the packages that you need.
These are the delimiters:

> ",; \t\n"

Then you can set by following way:

```
mybatis.type-aliases-package = com.company.entity.users,com.company.entity.departments,com.company.entity.students
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
mybatis.type-aliases-package = com.company.entity.**
```

it will include all class under packages 'entity' and under this for type alias.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: srry... but I can't find the document that explains why this works. At first I tried first answer but (probably because of my poor yml understanding?) it didn't work. wondering on net I found someone use path like 'com.test.demo.dto.**.something', and tried this, and it worked. I hope somebody will make it up.

Comment: but anyway i edited a bit